# Convert a multidimensional array to an XML object in PHP

Tags: php, xml, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array like this:

```
$array = array(

    "hello" => "hola",

    "another_array" => array(
        "key" => "best key ever",
        "another" => "yes, another key",
     ),

    "coolarray" => array(
        "bool" => true,
        "string" => "this is a string!",
    ),
);
```

I want a class like this:

```
class MyClass {

    public $array;

    public function __construct($array) {
        // something
        $this->array_to_xml($array);
    }

    public function array_to_xml($array) {
        // convert array to xml
    }
```

Then I want to be able to do things like this:

```
$string = $this->array->coolarray->string;
```

How can I do that?

Comment: @Martijn I have tried 3 of the answers in that and I still don't know how to use it as an object like this: `$string = $this->array->coolarray->string;`

Answer (score 1):

This gets asked a lot

Not sure why you mention XML, sounds like you just want an object.

See this answer for example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11854285/543455

`$obj = json_decode(json_encode($array));`

Comment: Never used JSON before. I'll give that a go. I mentioned XML because I'm making my own version of an open-source project which uses XML conversion. I tried to modify it and I broke it.

Comment: Update: It's saying that I'm trying to get a property of a non-object.

Comment: Okay, this is very bad practie. Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4790485/801496 It's much better way.

Comment: I'm reserving judgement on the bad practice call. Two built in function calls versus recursive user land functions, I'm honestly not sure what is the best approach and i suspect it largely depends on the array you are converting