# PHP Array to JSON: Trying to get property of a non-object error

Tags: php, arrays, object, json

I'm getting "trying to get a property of a non-object" when I'm trying to get values from an array I converted to JSON.

Snippet of `Utils.php`:

```
class Utils {

    public $config;

    public function __construct($config) {
        $this->config = json_decode(json_encode($config));
    }
```

Snippet of `System.php`:

```
require_once("Utils.php");
class System extends Utils {
// a bunch of functions
public function bind($port) {
// stuff
$this->writeOutput("Host: {$this->config->MySQL->Host}");
```

Snippet of `Game.php`:

```
require_once("Config.php");
$utils = new Utils($config);
```

What Config.php is a bit like:

```
$config = array(

"array" => array(
    "Key" => "Value", 
    "Key2" => "Value"
),

"anotherarray" => array(
    "AnotherKey" => "AnotherValue", 
    "ItsAnArray" => array("key" => "value"),
),

);
```

It's saying the errors are with every use of $this->config in System.php. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why would you encode/decode an array to JSON in the same line?

Comment: It was an answer on my previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21684375/convert-a-multidimensional-array-to-an-xml-object-in-php

Comment: That was some go horse programming, huh? Please post the complete error detail with lines.

Comment: @Will it's really bad. See my comment on that answer in your previous question.

Comment: As for your 'non-object' issue, do you run constructor for `System` object when use it? I can see where you're getting new instance of Utils object, but not System.

Comment: I thought that it would inherit $this->config as it extends Utils.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the **$config** parameter in constructor by using

```
public function __construct($config) {
    $this->config = (object) $config;
}
```

But, remember: converting array into a object is not recursively. So, you'll have to access the property using this:

```
$util = new Util($config);

print_r($util->config->array['key']);
```

As the question still in the same error, try using this:

```
require_once("Utils.php");
class System extends Utils {

   public function __construct($config){
      parent::__construct($config);
   }

   // a bunch of functions
   public function bind($port) {
      // stuff
      $this->writeOutput("Host: {$this->config->MySQL->Host}");
   }
}

$v = new System($array);
```

Comment: It still says "trying to get a property of a non-object".