# convert multidimensional array to object in php

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

i have seen a lot of examples but was unsuccessful to help myself. I have a multidimensional array that i want to convert to object format. I tried going levels deeper (multidimensional) but that all. I want to make it an php object. This is my scenario

```
// this is my array

Array
(
[_cars] => Array
    (
        [_car] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [_types] => Array
                            (
                                [_type] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [_cc] => 100
                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [_cc] => 100
                                            )

                                        [2] => Array
                                            (
                                                [_cc] => 1000
                                            )

                                    )

                            )
                        ) 
                    )
            )
    ) 
) 

// this is what i want

[_cars] => stdClass Object
    (
        [_car] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [_types] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [_type] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [_cc] => 999999999999
                                            )

                                        [1] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [_cc] => 999999999999
                                            )

                                        [2] => stdClass Object
                                            (
                                                [_cc] => 999999999999
                                            )

                                    )

                            )
                    )
             )
        )
```

Comment: Here's your answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790453/php-recursive-array-to-object Pretty straightforward ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if it will work but you can try

```
$object = json_decode(json_encode($array));
```

Comment: Hmm @ÁlvaroGonzález Have you an example of what would make this fail? Not trying to be a pain, I am just interested

Comment: @RiggsFolly Sure, here's an [example with a `DateTime` object](https://3v4l.org/Ye52B) that becomes a `stdClass` one. You could argue that's exactly the spec but it can be confusing if you didn't expect it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thanks for this. Wasn't aware of the DateTime conversion

Answer (score 0):

Please check this if this okay

```
$obj = new stdClass($array); or
$obj = json_decode(json_encode($array));
```